# Change type of matching parentheses in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, editors

I am working in TexStudio (2.9.0). I want to change the type of a pair of matching parenthesis. For example,

```
\command{something (involving (even)(more)parenthesis)}
```

should become

```
\command{something [involving (even)(more)parenthesis]}
```

Note that the parenthesis after `something` changed from `( )` to `[ ]`.

Am I overlooking a feature of TeXstudio? Might this be possible with user-defined makros?

---

*As a remark: Creation of these parentheses is easily possible by selecting the text and pressing the opening parenthesis of the desired type. So a selected `text` becomes `(text)` on pressing `(`. Unfortunately, there is no way to later change this comfortably to `[text]`.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed this is possible with a user macro. the key is the function `app.jumpToBracket()` which stands behind `Idefix -> Prentheses -> Jump to Match`. If the cursor is at one bracket, it moves to the other.

After placing the cursor before the first bracket, run

```
%SCRIPT
cursor.deleteChar()
cursor.insertText('[')
app.jumpToBracket()
cursor.deleteChar()
cursor.insertText(']')
```

That's the basic principle. You may add additional checks that the cursor is really next to a bracket and/or make it work if the cursor is after the bracket (use `cursor.deletePreviousChar()` instead).