# How to determine if a macro argument contains the macro itself?

Tags: conditionals, programming, etoolbox, recursion

I would like to have a way to detect if a particular macro's argument contains that particular macro itself. Consider the following MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*{\hasself}[1]{%
  #1 \ifboolexpr{
    % what goes here?
  }{1}{0}%
}

\begin{document}
This should return `Test 1 0': \hasself{Test\hasself{}}

This should return `Test 0': \hasself{Test}
\end{document}
```

What should the bool test be for this to work? Or is there another method to accomplish the same goal?

The use case is LaTeX2e, but I'm open to seeing Plain TeX, LaTeX3, LaTeX4, ..., etc. solutions as well.

I'd like the solution to work at any level of grouping within the argument if possible. If it makes a difference, you can assume that the argument will not be `\long` (so I guess I really could have used `\newcommand*` in the MNWE: updated). It's not necessary to catch equivalently-`\def`ed macros for my usage, but it would be nice to see it if it's even possible.

Comment: It depends what you mean by contains and equality. `\hasself{Test\hasself{}}` is true but what about `\hasself{Test{\hasself{}}}` {not at top level) or `\let\xhasself\hasself\hasself{Test\xhasself{}}` (macro contains an `\ifx` equivalent macro) or `\def\xhasself{\hasself}\hasself{Test\xhasself{}}` macro contained after an expansion .....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: For the purposes of the question, I'd like it to work at any level of grouping, but we can relax to only check for the original `csname` (that is, don't worry about checking for `\xhasself` in your example).

Comment: But that's the point, it is (depending on method used) hard to distinguish `\hasself` from `\xhassself` as they are `\ifx` equivalent.

Comment: what is the actual use case (almost certainly it's easier to solve the real use case than this form of the question:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm trying to create a solution to [Change type of matching parentheses in TeXstudio](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235232). Using `\mkbibparens`/`\mkbibbrackets` from `biblatex` almost does it, but it nests in "the wrong direction" so my plan was to check if there was only one "level" or more than one.

Comment: The reason I asked for a more general solution is because I think it'd be useful in other situations, too.

Comment: Usually one sets something using the macro, like \beentherefalse,\beentheretrue and \ifbeenthere.  In your case, you might want to increment and decrement and counter for each level.

Comment: See the use case is easier than the question (as for that use case you can check while executing the content, whereas just answering the question of whether there is a recursive use without executing any other content requires token scanning as in wipets answer)

Answer (score 3):

Since `counters` are global quantities in LaTeX, I decided to use them to approach your problem.  This doesn't give quite the answer you requested, because it prints the innermost result before it prints the outermost result in the nest.  That means, for your first example, that the output is "0 1" rather than "1 0".  But I'm thinking that, for what you want to use it for, that might be acceptable.

The output is actually the level of recursion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{hcount}
\newcommand*{\hasself}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{hcount}{-1}%
  \edef\hbefore{\thehcount}%
  #1\ %
  \the\numexpr\thehcount-\hbefore\relax%
  \addtocounter{hcount}{1}%
}
\def\junk#1{\hasself{#1}}

\begin{document}
This should return `Test 1 0': \hasself{Test\hasself{}}

This should return `Test 0': \hasself{Test}

\hasself{Test\hasself{Test\hasself{}}}

\hasself{Test\junk{Test\hasself{}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution by Steven is based on the fact that the parameter is processed. I show another solution here: the parameter is only scanned token by token.
The solution is based on the code available at [OPmac tricks www page](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#readtoks). Only few lines are added in order to implement the actual task here.

```
%% the code from http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#readtoks :

\newtoks\readtoksT \newif\ifreadtoksG
\def\readtoks{\begingroup \let\bgroup=\relax \let\egroup=\relax
   \readtoksT={}\readtoksGfalse \afterassignment\readtoksA \let\next= }
\def\readtoksA{\futurelet\tmpc\readtoksB}
\def\readtoksB{\let\next=\readtoksD \csname readtoksX\endcsname
   \ifcat\space\noexpand\tmpc \let\next=\readtoksC \def\nexxt{\readtoksD{ }}\fi
   \ifcat{\noexpand\tmpc      \let\next=\readtoksC \let\nexxt=\readtoksE \fi
   \ifcat}\noexpand\tmpc      \let\next=\readtoksC \let\nexxt=\readtoksF \fi
   \next
}
\def\readtoksC{\afterassignment\nexxt \let\next= }
\def\readtoksD#1{\readtoksT=\expandafter{\the\readtoksT#1}\readtoksA}
\def\readtoksE{\begingroup \readtoksGtrue \readtoksT={}\readtoksA}
\def\readtoksF{\ifreadtoksG
   \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\readtoksT\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
      {\expandafter\the\expandafter\readtoksT\expandafter{\the\readtoksT}}%
      \expandafter\readtoksA
   \else
      \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\readtoksO\expandafter{\the\readtoksT}%
   \fi
}
\def\readtoksO{\toks1}

%% The code for this actual task:

\newif\iftokenfound
\def\testtoken#1#2{{\global\tokenfoundfalse
   \def\readtoksX{\ifx\tmpc#1\global\tokenfoundtrue\fi}%
   \readtoks{#2}% 
}}

\def\hasself#1{\testtoken\hasself{#1}%   
   \iftokenfound Yes, hasself is present.
   \else         hasself isn't present.
   \fi
}

%%% Test:

NO:   \hasself{Normal {text}}

YES:  \hasself{Special {text \hasself{in group}}}

\bye
```